# How can I get the name of a calling program over an app server connection?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a program called `Test.p`. The program calls another program `ServerTest.p` via an appserver call.

In `ServerTest.p`, I want to know the name of the program that called (in this case `Test.p`).  I tried using the `program-name()` function but it only gives me a stack trace for the current appserver.

How can I find out what program called `ServerTest.p`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  On the face of it you would be adding coupling between the client and the app server and that would seem like a very bad idea.  Much like when developers use program-name() to change behavior within a session.

Comment: @TomBascom Because I have a program that is called via Appserver and I wanted to get a stack trace to find out where an error was originating from

Answer (score 0):

A simple and basic solution is to use an input parameter.

**ServerTest.p**

```
DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER wpic-name AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.

/* wpic-name = "Test.p" */
```

**Test.p**

```
RUN ServerTest.p(INPUT "Test.p").
```

Comment: This is not a very good solution since it requires changing calling program as well as called program. (But I cannot produce a better one myself at this moment)...

Comment: @Jensd: Thank's for your return. I totally agree with you, but like you, I have no better. That's why I said it was basic. :) We can improve it with an include that uses program-name() function in all callers programs to be more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOURCE-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME. So in your case you could use

```
    if SOURCE-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME EQ "Test.p" or 
       SOURCE-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME EQ Test.r"  then
    do:
```